# How can I ask a translation or homework question?

Tags: support, faq, asking-questions

I have some questions of the following types:

- English to Latin translation
- Latin to English translation
- Homework questions

What's the best way to ask these sorts of questions here?

---

<sup>Related: [What do we do with translation requests?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25/12)</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a translation service.  It's also not a "do your homework for you" service.  It *is*, however, a question and answer site for students of Latin, from beginners to experts.

So how can you ask translation and homework-related questions?  The key is to **show your work**.

That means:

- Try to figure out the answer yourself.
- Explain why you were unable to get a satisfactory answer on your own.

## Research effort

The first step is doing your own research.  Here are a few tips.

For translation questions, use the following resources to try to identify the best words that would meet your needs:

- Dictionaries like [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3atext%3a1999.04.0059) and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/) (see [the dictionary question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) for more options)
- Word study tools, like that of [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?)
- Lemmatization tools, like that of [Collatinus](http://outils.biblissima.fr/en/collatinus-web/index.php) (also available as desktop software)

For other types of questions, consider checking:

- Grammars like those of [Bennett](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/15665/15665-h/15665-h.htm) and [Gildersleeve](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU0BIAbE0SIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- Corpora like [The Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/) and [Packhum](http://latin.packhum.org/search)
- We also have [a list of self study material](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/957/79) which you might find helpful

## Explain

After having done your research, **explain why it did not answer your question**.  Tell us:

- which resources you checked
- what you found in each one
- what you still hope to learn

## Summary

Homework and translation questions are welcome here, but we expect you to:

- Demonstrate that you have researched your question, and
- Explain why your research still leaves you with a question

If you follow these guidelines, your question will be more likely to attract upvotes, and less likely to be closed.